# OpenCV DNN face detection in UWP/C++: bad results

Tags: c++, uwp, face-detection, opencv, python

I'm using OpenCV and Cafe to perform face detection on some images I receive from a stream. First, I tried with python:

```
    prototxt_file = 'deploy.prototxt'
    weights_file = 'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel'
    dnn = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt_file, weights_file)

    for image in images:
      blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), 
                                  (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

      dnn.setInput(blob)
      detections = dnn.forward()

      for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
              confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
              box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7]
              if confidence > 0.5:
                    //Do something
```

This works quite well. Now, I want to do the same within a C++ Windows UWP App, so I compiled OpenCV from source for UWP (tried with versions 3.4.1 and 4.3.0). After going through [this example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.cpp#L155-L158) I tried the following:

```
        std::string caffeConfigFilePath = "deploy.prototxt";
        std::string caffeWeightFilePath = "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel";
        net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(caffeConfigFilePath, caffeWeightFilePath);

        for (image in images)
        {
          cv::Mat imageResized, imageBlob;
          std::vector<cv::Mat> outs;

          cv::resize(image, imageResized, cv::Size(300, 300));
          cv::dnn::blobFromImage(imageResized, imageBlob, 1, cv::Size(300, 300),
                  (104.0, 177.0, 123.0));

          net.setInput(imageBlob, "data");
          net.forward(outs, "detection_out");

          CV_Assert(outs.size() > 0);
          for (size_t k = 0; k < outs.size(); k++)
          {
             float* data = (float*)outs[k].data;
             for (size_t i = 0; i < outs[k].total(); i += 7)
             {
                float confidence = data[i + 2];
                if (confidence > 0.5)
                {
                        //Do something
                }
             }
          }
```

This gives me very bad results. I get a lot of detections with a confidence of 1.0, covering the entire image. The face itself, however, is not detected. So I thought I might be reading the output wrong. I also tried the code posted with [this question](https://answers.opencv.org/question/195031/problem-with-facedetection-model-from-dnn-module/), but the results are the same. I checked everything I could think of (input images in right format, model correctly loaded, etc.) but could not identify the error.

Since the DNN module is usually not included in an OpenCV UWP build (I had to comment some lines in the CMake.txt, but then it compiled without errors), can it be that using it is just not possible from a UWP app? What else could be the reason the code is working in python, but an almost identical code is not working in C++?

Comment: I'm curious since I want to use dnn in a hololens app myself, how did you compile it for UWP? The dnn module is disabled for UWP in the cmake file. Also the line net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(caffeConfigFilePath, caffeWeightFilePath); will not work in UWP with the file access restrictions. Are you sure your model is loaded correctly?

Comment: @Roest You are right, the dnn module is usually disabled for UWP in cmake, but I just commented these lines in the modules/dnn/CMakeList.txt, and then it built without errors. Of course, this doesn't mean it is working. This is partly why I asked here, to find out whether someone had any success with using it.
Concerning loading the model, I added the .prototxt and .caffemodel directly as content in my VS solution, and I tried to verify the model by printing the layers & parameters, which gave me the same results as in python. Still not 100% certain the model is loaded correctly though...